# Scrape webpage data with proxy

Tags: c#, web, screen-scraping

The following code scrapes the source of the inputted site, I want to do the same - but with a proxy inputted by the user.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter path");
string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Page OK");
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader readStream = null;

    if (response.CharacterSet == null)
    {
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
    }
    else
    {
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
    }

    string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();


    response.Close();
    readStream.Close();
    Console.WriteLine(data);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@fileName, data);
```

I have tried the following code - but i get the error: System.UriFormatException

```
Console.WriteLine("proxy ip:");
string proxyip = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("port");
string proxyport = Console.ReadLine();
string proxyaddress = (proxyip + ":" + proxyport);
HttpWebRequest requestproxy = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(proxyaddress, false);
requestproxy.Proxy = myproxy;
HttpWebResponse responseproxy = (HttpWebResponse)requestproxy.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("file path:");
string fileName = Console.ReadLine();

if (responseproxy.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Page OK");
    Stream receiveStream = responseproxy.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader readStream = null;

    if (responseproxy.CharacterSet == null)
    {
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
    }
    else
    {
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(responseproxy.CharacterSet));
    }

    string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

    responseproxy.Close();
    readStream.Close();
    Console.WriteLine(data);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@fileName, data);
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example you append a string:

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);

In the second example you forgot to change "url" to the urlAddress string.

HttpWebRequest requestproxy = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");

This would cause the System.UriFormatException error.

Answer (score 0):

The applicable WebProxy constructors are looking for a string (a URL) or a URI in it first argument.

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.webproxy(v=vs.110).aspx

A hostname + ":" + a port number does not meet the criteria for a URL within a string.  You need "http://xxxxxx" or "https://xxxxx"